# Why does the sum of 2 parseFloat variables give me an incorrect decimal number

Tags: javascript, function, sum

If I have this little function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function printFloat(){
      var myFloatNumber1 = document.getElementById('floatNumber1');
      var myFloatNumber2 = document.getElementById('floatNumber2');
      alert(parseFloat(myFloatNumber1.value) + parseFloat(myFloatNumber2.value))
 }

</script>

<input type="text" id="floatNumber1"></input>
<input type="text" id="floatNumber2"></input>

<input type="button" onclick="printFloat()"/>
```

in field 1 I enter: 221.58
in field 2 I enter: 2497.74

I expect the sum of 2 numbers in the input fields to be a 2 number digit: 2719.32
But the result is a incorrect number... : 2719.3199999999997

a round would do the job, but I just don't get why the code does that on this number...
On other number combinations, the sum is correct...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [The Floating-Point-Guide:](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/)

> **Why don’t my numbers, like 0.1 + 0.2 add up to a nice round 0.3, and
>   instead I get a weird result like
>   0.30000000000000004?**
>
> Because internally, computers use a
>   format (binary floating-point) that
>   cannot accurately represent a number
>   like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.
>
> When the code is compiled or
>   interpreted, your “0.1” is already
>   rounded to the nearest number in that
>   format, which results in a small
>   rounding error even before the
>   calculation happens.

In your case, the rounding errors happen when the values you entered are converted by `parseFloat()`.

> **Why do other calculations like 0.1 + 0.4 work correctly?**
>
> In that case, the result (0.5) can be
>   represented exactly as a
>   floating-point number, and it’s
>   possible for rounding errors in the
>   input numbers to cancel each other out
>   - But that can’t necessarily be relied upon (e.g. when those two numbers were
>   stored in differently sized floating
>   point representations first, the
>   rounding errors might not offset each
>   other).
>
> In other cases like 0.1 + 0.3, the
>   result actually isn’t really 0.4, but
>   close enough that 0.4 is the shortest
>   number that is closer to the result
>   than to any other floating-point
>   number. Many languages then display
>   that number instead of converting the
>   actual result back to the closest
>   decimal fraction.

Answer (score 6):

simply do following.

```
function printFloat(){
      var myFloatNumber1 = document.getElementById('floatNumber1');
      var myFloatNumber2 = document.getElementById('floatNumber2');
      var total=parseFloat(myFloatNumber1.value) + parseFloat(myFloatNumber2.value);
      alert(total.toFixed(2));
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

See:

- [Weird Javascript Behaviour: Floating Point Addition giving the wrong answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036662/weird-javascript-behaviour-floating-point-addition-giving-the-wrong-answer)
- [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)
- [Understanding floating point variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480699/understanding-floating-point-variables)