# New to JavaScript; Trying to Understand Why My Loop Isn't Running Properly When I Plugin Different Values

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding/JavaScript and I'm trying to understand why one of my loops refuses to run as I intended.

Basically, I am setting a loop that only outputs a certain part (fraction) of 100. As you can see in the snapshot, everything works fine when I am outputting quarters. However, when I attempt to output tenths, the loop stops after two-tenths, when it should output ten-tenths.

Both loops are exactly the same, syntax wise. Would anyone mind explaining why one runs, while the other doesn't? Thanks in advance!

```
var quarter = .25;
for (x = 1; x <=100; x++)
{
    if (x / 100 === quarter)
    {
       console.log (x + " is one of the quarter");
       quarter = quarter + .25;
    }
}

console.log (" ");

var part = .1;
for (x = 1; x <=100; x++)
{
    if (x / 100 === part)
    {
       console.log (x + " is one of the part");
       part = part + .1;
}
```

}

[Snapshot of Editor + Terminal with Code in Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awwgc.png)

Comment: Please copy & paste your code sample into your question instead of linking to a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out:

**code**

```
var part=0.1;
for(x=1;x<=100;x++){
if(x/100===part){
   console.log(x);
   part=parseFloat((part+.1).toFixed(1));
}
}
```

The problem is 0.1+0.1+0.1= 0.300000004 in javascript which can be fixed using the above code

Answer (score 0):

The reason is JS not good at floating point addition, and it will not output what you noramlly will expect

```
> console.log(0.2+.1)
> 0.30000000000000004
```

Copied from another stackoverflow([Weird Javascript Behaviour: Floating Point Addition giving the wrong answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036662/weird-javascript-behaviour-floating-point-addition-giving-the-wrong-answer))

It has to do with how decimal values are converted to binary floating point numbers. 1/10 turns into a repeating decimal in binary, so the number is not perfectly represented, and repeated operations can expose the error.

JavaScript uses IEEE-754 floating point numbers, for the record. Some other languages have the same problem.

checkout this also:
[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)